# Convert linq query to string array - C#

Tags: c#, linq, arrays, string, casting

What is the most efficient way of converting a single column linq query to a string array?

```
private string[] WordList()
    {
        DataContext db = new DataContext();

        var list = from x in db.Words
                   orderby x.Word ascending
                   select new { x.Word };

       // return string array here
    }
```

Note - x.Word is a string

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I prefer the lambda style, and you really ought to be disposing your data context.

```
private string[] WordList()
{
    using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {
       return db.Words.Select( x => x.Word ).OrderBy( x => x ).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like to give the gc a workout! - just kidding - this is a very good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
return list.ToArray();
```

This is presuming that `x.Word` is actually a string.

Otherwise you could try:

```
return list.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: The first way gives this error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1[]' to 'string[]'. The second method works! Thanks!

Comment: Skip the new {} in your select and you won't have to unpack the anonymous type, you'll just have a string (assuming Word is a character column).

Comment: @tvanfosson,  What does it mean to "*unpack an anonymous type*"?  (I'm assuming an edit has been made to this answer, because I no longer see any `new {}`.)

Answer (score 4):

if you type it in Lambda syntax instead you can do it a bit easier with the ToArray method:

```
string[] list = db.Words.OrderBy(w=> w.Word).Select(w => w.Word).ToArray();
```

or even shorter:

```
return db.Words.OrderBy(w => w.Word).Select(w => w.Word).ToArray();
```

Comment: both give error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'Word[]' to 'string[]'

Comment: Corrected it, missed the .Word bit