# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<char[]>' to 'string[]'

Tags: arrays, linq, c#-4.0

I am trying to convert the result of a linq statement into string[] array
like below

```
string[] g = from p in db.np_user_security where 
p.user_id == user_id select p.group_id.Distinct().ToArray();
```

but giving me an error as below

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'string[]'

The query return a list of ids and I need to save it in array of string or long. What Am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert linq query to string array - C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378801/convert-linq-query-to-string-array-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `p.group_id.Distinct().ToArray()` you split each `group_id` into array of distinct characters. So in fact, the entire query returns `IQueryable` of *array of characters*, not ids.

I believe you want to wrap the query with parens first before calling `Distinct().ToArray()` :

```
string[] g = (from p in db.np_user_security 
              where p.user_id == user_id 
              select p.group_id
              ).Distinct().ToArray();
```